# Render User control as string template

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

what do you think of rendering user control as a string template, basically an implementation like [Irenderable implementation](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/19/Render-User-Control-as-String-Template.aspx) do you guys think it has any cons. One of the pros that i came across was that i can use my user controls to simply return the required HTML for ajax calls.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this approach to render html for emails or PDF. I've done a lot of hackery to grab my pages and render their output to a string builder so I can convert them or email.

I do this when you need a print to pdf for the current page, or email this page and you want to send the html that the user is currently looking at.

Comment: Performance overload would depend on the load of your site and the page being rendered. I haven't had any problems yet.